# What should I look for when selecting lights for indoor cacti?

Tags: houseplants, light, cactus

We grow cacti indoors due to the weather (UK).

What should we look for when selecting lights? We have had mixed results with a new lighting system and have started to lose some.

[image: See one of the old guys clearly dying/dead and my precious Euphorbia Obesa beginning to bolt]

See one of the old guys clearly dying/dead and my precious Euphorbia Obesa beginning to bolt

Comment: @kevinsky - To start with we had two of [these](http://www.aquaristikonline.ch/catalog/dennerle-trocal-plant-125w-p-695.html?language=en) but they were expensive in electricity and one of them died within a few months. We couldn't find a replacement. We've recently tried an aquarium strip light but that seems not to be too effective as some of the cacti are beginning to look pale.

Comment: Nice collection. What direction is the window facing?

Comment: Doesn't matter much - trees block out much of the light - but it's north east ish.

Answer (score 3):

With a north facing window in a northern climate you effectively have no outside light source as far as cacti are concerned.  Your primary light source must be artificial and lots of it.

Check this [answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4438/what-kind-of-light-is-needed-for-moss-and-ferns/4440#4440).  It's about moss but the light requirements are the same.

[This gardener](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14054/how-can-i-keep-my-flamingo-plants-small-for-a-terrarium) is having good luck indoors with "a 50W HID lamp (directly above this plant), and a 150W HQI lamp".

This [question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5680/what-is-the-best-light-spectrum-for-growing-chili-peppers/5681#5681) about growing chili peppers indoors is also relevant.

To sum up, you need:

- lots of light
- positioned close to the plants
- if you use HID lights you will probably need a fan to distribute the heat
- a mixture of HID, fluorescent and high pressure sodium will work
- be prepared for the electrical bills as the lights should be on about 16 hours a day
- for HID or high pressure sodium they draw a considerable amount of power. Ensure that your household circuitry can take it.
- cheapest and coolest solution is lots of fluorescents suspended twelve to eighteen inches from the plants but this will not match the light output of the other types
- LED lights do not seem to provide enough illumination

Comment: LED lights *can* provide enough illumination, but from my perusal of the market, there are currently a lot of low light producing scam-rigs out there.